# Is there a way to dynamically add constraints in Scala?

Tags: scala, oop

I'm trying to simulate a bakery that accepts online orders from customers.

For this I have 4 classes:

- Customer:

  - age
  - money
  - gender
- Order:

  - day
  - hour
  - Customer
- Bakery:

  - name
- Bread:

  - size
  - color
  - taste
  - name

I would like to be able to add orders to a Baakery with some constraints. For example:

- "Only allow an order if the customer is older than 18"
- "If the customer is older than 18 and younger than 30, only allow the order if it is for white bread"
- "If the customer is older than 65, only allow the order if the taste is 'good' "

Of course these can be written as if-else constructs in a baker.addOrder(o: Order) function but my question is: Is there a way to add these dynamically. So for example like:

- baker.addConstraint(customer.age, ">18")
- baker.addAndConstraint(customer.age, "">18", customer.age, "<30", bread.color == "white")

Is there a way to do this or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define these constraints as functions and collect them based on configuration into a list of active constraints to give to your bakery.

For example

```
case class Customer(age: Int)
case class Order(customer: Customer, breadType: String)


// define a constraint as a function that checks an Order 
// and returns an error message if it is rejected
type OrderConstraint =  Order => Option[String]

// some example constraints
val ofAge: OrderConstraint = order => 
  if (order.customer.age < 18) Some("Too young to order") else None

val whiteBreadOnly: OrderConstraint = order => 
  if (order.breadType != "white") Some("Only white bread available now") else None

// these can now be collected according to runtime conditions
val tuesday = true
val constraints =  if (tuesday) Seq( whiteBreadOnly, ofAge) else Seq( ofAge )

val anOrder = Order(Customer(12), "wholegrain")

// and checked to produce a list of errors
// (empty means the order was okay )
constraints.flatMap(_.apply(anOrder))
```